# How can i set up all the data's in the textbox

Tags: c#, sql, linq

first of all there is a searchbox form and a view form. after passing the value of the id in the searchbox, it should return all the values that matches with the id of that person after the textchange method occured. but it doesn't display a single value on the textboxes. here is my code

```
 public void first_tab_search(string key)
        {
            key = txtSearch.Text;
            var first = from a in dbcon.personal_informations where a.last_name == key select a;
            foreach (var setThem in first)
            {
                txtsurname.Text = setThem.last_name;
                txtfirstname.Text = setThem.first_name;
                txtmiddlename.Text = setThem.middle_name;
                txtID.Text = setThem.userid;
                txtweight.Text = setThem.weight;
                txttin.Text = setThem.tin;
                txtsss.Text = setThem.sss;
                txtaeno.Text = setThem.agency_employee_no;
                txtbloodtype.Text = setThem.blood_type;
                txtcitizenship.Text = setThem.citizenship;
                txtcivilstatus.Text = setThem.civil_status;
                txtcpno.Text = setThem.cell_no;
                txtdob.Text = setThem.datetime_of_birth.ToString();
                txtemail.Text = setThem.email_address;
                txtgender.Text = setThem.sex;
                txtgsis.Text = setThem.gsis_id;
                txtheight.Text = setThem.height;
                txtnameext.Text = setThem.name_ext;
                txtpagibig.Text = setThem.pagibig_id;
                txtpermaaddr.Text = setThem.permanent_address;
                txtpermatelno.Text = setThem.permanent_telno;
                txtpermazip.Text = setThem.permanent_zipcode;
                txtphilhealth.Text = setThem.philhealth;
                txtpob.Text = setThem.place_of_birth;
                txtresidentialaddr.Text = setThem.residential_address;
                txtresitelno.Text = setThem.residential_telno;
                txtresizip.Text = setThem.residential_zipcode;
                txtweight.Text = setThem.weight;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Did you try to debug it and watch the values in `first`?
By the way, what's the point of setting the same text boxes every time in a loop?

Answer (score 2):

You have a whole host of problems going on here.

1. You pass a key into the method, and then immediately overwrite it with the contents of your search box.
2. Your search could return more than one result, and therefore your code is looping through each result and overwriting the output values with the last returned row. Use += rather than + in your loop, i.e.

   txtsurname.Text += setThem.last_name;
3. Your code is currently case sensitive, this may be the desired approach but might not be.